# How to tell the static checker that a property never changes when it is unprovable?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

My class has a property that is initialized in the constructor and is never supposed to change. Methods all around my codebase accept that class as a parameter and rely on that property satisfying a certain condition.

The key point is that it is really unprovable that the property never changes. I can personally "swear" that it never changes (and I have unit tests for it, too), but it cannot be proved formally (or at least I think so).

Consider the following reduced example:

```
    public class ConstantPoperty
    {
        public class SomeClass
        {
            public int SomeProp { 
                get { return GetSomePropThroughUnprovableMechanism(); }
            }

            public SomeClass( int i )
            {
                SetSomePropThroughUnprovableMechanism( i );
            }
        }

        public void Method( SomeClass c )
        {
            Contract.Requires( c != null );
            Contract.Requires( c.SomeProp == 5 );
        }

        public void FalsePositive()
        {
            SomeClass c = new SomeClass( 5 );
            if ( c.SomeProp != 5 ) return;
            Method( c );
            Method( c ); // unproven requires: c.SomeProp == 5
        }
    }
```

Note that the first call to `Method()` get an OK from the checker, since I've checked right before it that the condition is satisfied.
The second call, however, gets an *unproven* warning. My guess is, the checker assumes that the first call to `Method(c)` might change `c.SomeProp` so that it will no longer satisfy the condition.

From this, I can deduce two possible workarounds, neither of which I consider acceptable:

1. Add `Contract.Ensures( c.SomeProp == Contract.OldValue( c.SomeProp ) )` to `Method`, as well as to every other method that accepts arguments of type `SomeClass`.
   One can easily see how this is absolutely ridiculous.
2. Add a redundant check for `c.SomeProp == 5` before the second call to `Method(c)`.
   While this is less ridiculous than the first option, it is also unacceptable, because in addition to cluttering the code, it will also have a performance penalty (such a check will not be optimized away).

The ideal solution would be to somehow convince the checker that `SomeProp` is never supposed to change after construction, but I couldn't find any way to do this.

Or maybe I am missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite it like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly int _someProp;

    public int SomeProp { get { return _someProp; } }

    public SomeClass(int i)
    {
        _someProp = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Ok, I see my mistake now: I have incorrectly reduced the example. The key point here is that the property's unchangeable nature cannot be proven formally. It's not a simple, straightforward property, but it has some magic storage mechanism behind it. I know that it indeed never changes (and I have unit tests for that), but I don't know how to convince the checker. I have updated the original post to reflect this. Sorry for the confusion.